# Remover dado especifico em uma pilha

Tags: c#, .net, estrutura-de-dados, stack

Não faço a minima ideia de como remover um dado especifico de uma pilha. Tentei realizar o `minhaPilha.remove();` e não deu nada certo.

```
Console.WriteLine("<Pilha>");
Stack<string> minhaPilha = new Stack<string>();
Console.WriteLine("Para add itens, selecione X");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Para remover itens, selecione Z");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Caso queira remover um dado especifico digite W");

minhaPilha.Push("Primeira");
minhaPilha.Push("Segunda");
minhaPilha.Push("Terceira");
minhaPilha.Push("Quarta");

String opc = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (string carta in minhaPilha)
{
    Console.WriteLine(carta);
}

if (opc == "Z")
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    minhaPilha.Pop();

    foreach (string carta in minhaPilha)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(carta);
    }

}
if (opc == "X")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Digite aqui:");
    minhaPilha.Push(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (string carta in minhaPilha)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(carta);
    }
}
if (opc == "W")
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    minhaPilha.Pop();

    foreach (string carta in minhaPilha)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(carta);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Sei que não é possível fazer isto em uma pilha. No entanto, me foi passado por um mestre: desempilhe, depois remova o desejado e assim você empilha novamente tendo retirado o dado desejado.

Comment: O que você chama de "dado específico"? Você quer remover um item que não seja o último? Você sabe o que é uma pilha? Sabe que isto não pode ser feito nela?

Comment: Sim, sei que não é possível. No entanto, me foi passado essa dor de cabeça por um mestre e a lógica que ele deu foi. Desempilhe, depois remova o desejado e assim você empilha novamente tendo retirado o dado desejado.

Comment: Quando é assim, coloca toda informação possível na pergunta.

Comment: Valeu, bigown... iniciando agora no overflow.... Mais uma vez muito obrigado, vlh

Answer (score 1):

Por definição, uma pilha não permite o acesso/inserção/remoção aleatório.

Se precisas de remover um item específico, considera usar outra estrutura de dados, como a `List<T>`.

Mais uma nota: a classe `Stack` foi deprecada com a introdução de tipos genéricos no C# 2.0. Devias usar a versao genérica: [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx).

Dito isto, se realmente insistires em remover um item aleatório duma stack (apesar de ser altamente desaconselhado), terás de criar uma stack nova filtrada:

```
stack = new Stack<string>(stack.Where(carta => carta != "Segunda"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho que deveria usar outra estrutura, talvez até criar uma que use uma lista com métodos `Pop()` e `Push()`. Mas darei a solução que você pediu:

```
WriteLine("Qual elemento:");
var selecionado = ReadLine();
var novaPilha = new Stack<string>();
var totalItens = minhaPilha.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < totalItens; i++) {
    if (minhaPilha.Peek() == selecionado) {
        minhaPilha.Pop();
        break;
    } else {
        novaPilha.Push(minhaPilha.Pop());
    }
}
totalItens = novaPilha.Count;
for (var i = 0; i < totalItens; i++) {
    minhaPilha.Push(novaPilha.Pop());
}
foreach (var carta in minhaPilha) {
    WriteLine(carta);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zzLGn4). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X7kQpH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Stack.cs).

Não testei exaustivamente mas deve resolver. Ele faz justamente o desempilhamento até achar o que deve ser removido, e volta empilhar o que foi desempilhado. Tem formas melhores de fazer isto mas o fiz conforme seu requisito, que não faz sentido, mas como é exercício, deve ter um motivo.